# How to detect spiral optical flow using matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, curve-fitting, matlab-cvst, opticalflow

I have a video of a giant whirlpool, similar to the below image
[image]

Can anyone give an algorithm / code to detect SPIRAL OPTICAL FLOW?

Is it possible to fit a spiral curve over it depending on the spiral optical flow? If yes how?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can compute optical flow using `vision.OpticalFlow` object in the Computer Vision System Toolbox.  As for determining whether it is spiral, that seems to be the crux of your project.

Optical flow takes a pair of consecutive frames, and attempts to give you a vector at every pixel describing its motion from frame 1 to frame 2.

If you do not care about the motion of every single pixel you can track a sparse set of points over time using `vision.PointTracker`.

**Edit:**
If you have a recent version of the Computer Vision System Toolbox, try the new optical flow functions: `opticalFlowHS`, `opticalFlowLK`, `opticalFlowLKDoG`, and `opticalFlowFarneback`.

Comment: Is it possible to track the inward flow path and end up in the vortex using optical flow ?

Comment: That was the thing I was looking for. Thank you one again :)